# Inference Images look different than training images

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I have trained a GAN model on a training set it produces correct images (the target output styled image) but when I run inference it does not produce such images that look distorted and different than how it produces during training. What could be the possible reasons? It is trained on sufficient epochs with a training data size of about 11000 images.

The first image is during training and has the correct style. 2nd image is an inference image but does not have the same style.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, is the first image the generated image or is it a training sample?

Comment: The first image is generated during training. During training we save samples generated by the generator